# Javascript Puro: Multiplicar valores de tds em uma tabela e retornar o valor

Tags: javascript, tabela-html

Opa galera tudo blz? Estou com uma tabela de compras e gostaria de multiplicar a quantidade do produto com o seu valor retornando assim o resultado e somar todos os resultados.
Eu já consegui fazer isso, o problema está sendo para fazer com vários produtos ele só está multiplicando todos os valores de uma vez, preciso de ajuda.

```js
var quant = document.querySelectorAll(".quant");
var preco = document.querySelectorAll(".preco");
var total = 1;
    
for (var i = 0; i < quant.length && i < preco.length; i++)
{
   total*= Number(quant[i].innerHTML) * parseFloat(preco[i].innerHTML.toString().replace(",","."));
   document.querySelector(".valor").innerHTML = total.toString().replace(".",",");
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="tabela" border="1px">
      <tr>
          <td>Produto</td>
          <td>Quant</td>
          <td>Preço</td>
          <td>Valor Total</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Stawka</td>
          <td class="quant">3</td>
          <td class="preco">30,50</td>
          <td class="valor"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Stawka</td>
          <td class="quant">5</td>
          <td class="preco">25</td>
          <td class="valor"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que está usando o `for` talvez não seja a melhor, o melhor seria fazer o `for` por cada linha, para garantir que pega os valores da linha, mas primeiro vamos ver o que acontece no seu código:

- está usando o índice para pegar a quantidade e valor, mas não usa o índice para por o resultado, deveria ser algo como `document.querySelector(".valor")[i].innerHTML`;
- deve zerar o valor da soma para cada linha, por isso se quiser o total geral, deve usar outra variável.

Adaptei o código com essas duas correções, veja abaixo:

```js
var quant = document.querySelectorAll(".quant");
var preco = document.querySelectorAll(".preco");
var valor = document.querySelectorAll(".valor");
var totalLinha = 0;
var total = 0;
    
for (var i = 0; i < quant.length; i++)
{
   totalLinha = Number(quant[i].innerHTML) * parseFloat(preco[i].innerHTML.toString().replace(",","."));
   valor[i].innerHTML = totalLinha.toString().replace(".",",");
   total += totalLinha;
}

document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toString().replace(".",",");
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="tabela" border="1px">
      <tr>
          <td>Produto</td>
          <td>Quant</td>
          <td>Preço</td>
          <td>Valor Total</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Stawka</td>
          <td class="quant">3</td>
          <td class="preco">30,50</td>
          <td class="valor"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Stawka</td>
          <td class="quant">5</td>
          <td class="preco">25</td>
          <td class="valor"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>

Total: <span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Muito, muito obrigado mesmo, já tava a um tempão sem conseguir resolver isso